# Find element in native app Pushing command to appium work queue

Tags: android, automation, appium

I am automating the native app  by using appium. In my app i have following layout:

[image]

I find element like this:

```
WebElement fb= driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout"));
List<WebElement>                            
editText1=fb.findElements(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout"));
```

OR

```
List<WebElement> editText=driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
```

But i appium just searching the element like

```
Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.FrameLayout","context":"","multiple":false}]
```

in infinite loop 
Same thing working for other application.

Any one have any idea why appium is not finding any single element?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say from what you mentioned above, Why don't you share a clean example for what it actually happened, And try to use driver.findelement() instead of elements for single element.

Comment: Hi gaurav I just found that the apk is protected with progaud and it seems like that is the reason. If u have any idea on this please let me know